# useradd via ssh to remote server - how to elevate rights ?sudo?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, python-3.5

I want to create a user on a remote machine.  I can reach only via ssh.  useradd requires sudo, but the below script did not prompt me for my password and did not create the user.  How do I elevate rights on the remote machine?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import subprocess

HOST="192.168.1.71"

#useradd is linux - adduser is perl
addusertoremote = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" %HOST, "sudo useradd --disabled-login deletetom"],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
resulta = addusertoremote.stdout.readlines()
if resulta == []:
   errora = addusertoremote.stderr.readlines()
   print(errora)
else:
   print(resulta)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use paramiko module for SSH in python.

```
import paramiko
sshsession = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshsession.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sshsession.connect("hostname",username="username",password="password")

stdin, stdout, stderr = sshsession.exec_command('su')
stdin.write("password for root here")

sshsession.exec_command("sudo useradd --disabled-login deletetom")
#other commands here
sshsession.close()
```

Comment: The question is not how to ssh into the server.  My script works fine for that.  The question is how to elevate my rights so I can add a user.  I did install paramiko using pip to test your script, but it failed to create a user for me.  If you know how to elevate the rights w/o paramiko, I'd be very interested in that.  As far as I can tell, my script works fine, except I never become root.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, though I wouldn't recommend doing it.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "dummy", "-t", "sudo -S touch test.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


proc.stdin.write(password.encode("utf8"));
proc.stdin.write("\r\n".encode("utf8"))

print(proc.communicate())
```

After I logged into the host, the file had been created as root. Also, I am using keys to login so ssh doesn't ask for my password, but sudo does.

Comment: I had no problems with file manipulation, chmod, chgrp, etc.  Only with adding a user - which was prompting for a password which python simply had no way to answer.

Comment: This prompts for a password, because I did 'sudo'. You can see it in the output.

Answer (score -1):

I have done quite a bit of research on this and have come to the following conclusion.

Neither Python, nor Paramiko inside python has a method to elevate the rights on the reached machine.

One must ssh in AS root to the machine you want to create a user on - this way you already ARE root and no prompt is generated.

So, in my case (which I shall test soon), I would ssh into the machine that has the python script as myself, then su -s and become root and run the python script which will have root ssh into other machines to create accounts as root.

Comment: Works perfectly when one machine does ssh root@nextmachine.  I assume it would do the same with sudo if the user had no password.